# Generate inside module folder

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm working with an Angular 2 application based on Angular-CLI skeleton, I had the habit of structuring my src folder with one directory by module, and each component related to this module in the same folder.

```
src
    app
        documents
            document-list.component.ts
            document-list.component.html
            documents.component.ts
            documents.component.html
            document.module.ts
        app.component.ts
        app.module.ts
    main.ts
```

Now that I'm using Angular-CLI, I would like to take profit of each feature, but when I'm generating a new component, no matter what, it keep creating a new folder for my component when I just want to put it inside the related folder.

```
src
    app
        documents
            document-list
                document-list.component.ts
                document-list.component.html
            documents.component.ts
            documents.component.html
            document.module.ts
        app.component.ts
        app.module.ts
    main.ts
```

Is it possible to keep my previous structure, is it a bad practice? The guideline recommends to avoid useless directory depth so I'm kind of disturbed.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Assuming you are in your application's root directory and want to create components inside `src/app/documents` as you show above, you can use the `--flat` option to have your component created without creating a directory. To create the component as you request above, use this command:

```
ng generate component document-list --flat
```

Comment: No possibility of defining it as the default option in my `angular-cli.json`?

Comment: Not right now, but that could be added in the future, if it's something you'd like, file an issue on the repo.

Comment: Tested: it also can be used to generate a module without folder

Answer (score 25):

Using angular-cli you can run `ng g component documents/document-list` and it will create the structure you need, (assuming app is the root of your application).

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: The question is about NOT having the extra 'document-list' folder but having the component files inside the 'documents' folder.

Comment: But what if the structure already exists, and you want to add a new component folder as a nested component. Do you do `ng g c /existing-components-folder/new-component-folder`?

Answer (score 8):

To create a component inside a folder that either already exist or does not have the same name as the component without creating a sub folder...

ng generate component directory/component-name --flat

For example:
**ng generate component test/test-list --flat**

This will generate the component in the folder test and **NOT** create a sub folder test-detail...
[image]

Comment: Why the down votes, I tested it and this does work and relates to the original question..  As mentioned here "The question is about NOT having the extra 'document-list' folder but having the component files inside the 'documents' folder. – hogan Sep 17 '17 at 3:23"

Comment: Maybe is because the example image is as if you used `ng g c test-list` because `test` is very similar to `test-list`, maybe you can improve the example making two components in the same folder instead of only one. This is my opinion although I haven't downvoted you.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, you have the best answer